# Base64 PDF difference on different servers

Tags: pdf, base64

I have a webservice application that returns a base64 encoded PDF file, created with aspose. This webservice is now installed on a different (windows) server for testing purposes. However, when I call the webservice on the new server, the base64 is different than the original base64 on the first server.

I would like to understand why the base64 on the different servers are different. I converted the base64 to PDF and checked the PDF file, but it looks the same (besides the size of the PDF file that originally was 18kB, but is 14kB on the new server). Later we will need to install this webservice on multiple servers, where we hope that the base64 could be the same on all servers, so the base64 can be checked if the response is correct.

As far as I know there shouldn't be information about the server within the base64, so this couldn't be the different. Besides this the font that is used is also available on both servers. I already checked the metadata and didn't see any information here.

Could anyone help me and explain why these base64 are different and where the difference comes from?

Update:
I just uploaded the 2 PDF files, so it is easier to help me analyse the differences. These are the 2 PDF files:

Original server:
http://www.filedropper.com/pdforiginalserver

New server: 
http://www.filedropper.com/pdfnewserver

I hope this makes it easier to help me with this problem.

Comment: If you shared those two different pdfs, we could analyze them. As you don't, we cannot.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Needed to find out how to share the PDF files. I just uploaded them on a website and updated my question. Hope this information helps.

Comment: I'll look into that next week.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to look into the files. Unfortunately your filedropper links don't work anymore, so I cannot look into them now. Can you share again?

Comment: I just updated the filedropper links. Hope you can download them now. Let me know if they are still not working, then I will find another way/site to share them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDFs both embed a subset of the font Calibri, but on those two servers apparently different versions of that font were available to the PDF producer to create a subset from:

- On the original server Calibri version 6.18 (copyrighted 2016) was used.
- On the new server Calibri version 5.9.0 (copyrighted 2014) is used.

Comment: I copied the Calibri version from the original server and installed it on the new server, and now the PDFs are the same. Thank you for your help! How can you check the font version of the PDF files? Do you use a specific tool for this? I am curious, so I can find the problem myself if it occurs another time.

Comment: I inspected the fonts using FontForge.